# App crashes after writing this code. Where is the mistake?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I would like to code an easy counter app. I would like to implement some other tools later. Therefore I chose the "BottomNavigationView". In one of my Fragments I would like to implement the counter. The Layout is right and works but the code which really increase/decrease the number in the class `HomeActivity` crashes my app at start. Maybe somebody knows an answer? :D

i deleted the code from the `HomeActivity` to check if the crashes came from the new code and all works fine. Therefore the code for the counter has a mistake.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private TextView counterText;
    private Button plusButton;
    private Button minusButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    private int counter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        counterText = getView().findViewById(R.id.counterText);
        minusButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        plusButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        resetButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        initCounter();

    }

    private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.minusButton:
                    minusCounter();
                    break;
                case R.id.plusButton:
                    plusCounter();
                    break;
                case R.id.resetButton:
                    initCounter();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);



    }

    private void initCounter() {
        counter = 0;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }


    private void minusCounter() {
        counter--;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }

    private void plusCounter() {
        counter++;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
2019-02-10 19:35:22.065 15241-15241/? E/Zygote: v2
2019-02-10 19:35:22.065 15241-15241/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10229
2019-02-10 19:35:22.065 15241-15241/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
2019-02-10 19:35:22.066 15241-15241/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.067 15241-15241/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2019-02-10 19:35:22.068 15241-15241/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.counter1 
2019-02-10 19:35:22.072 15241-15241/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-02-10 19:35:22.097 15241-15241/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
2019-02-10 19:35:22.397 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.counter1-2/lib/arm
2019-02-10 19:35:22.433 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-02-10 19:35:22.579 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.example.counter1.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:16)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.counter1-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.co
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.664 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:652)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:794)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.example.counter1.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:16)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6955)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1642)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.665 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1386)
2019-02-10 19:35:22.751 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.752 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.874 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.875 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.893 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.894 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.909 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.911 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.912 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.912 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.918 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.920 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.920 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.921 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
2019-02-10 19:35:22.996 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-02-10 19:35:22.998 15241-15241/com.example.counter1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.counter1, PID: 15241
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.counter1/com.example.counter1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.counter1.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:38)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6972)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I expect that the counter counts +1 if the button get pressed and -1 if the other button get pressed.

P.S sorry for my English if there are mistakes. Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Please add the Logcat.

Comment: where can I find it?

Comment: Press Alt + 6 in Android Studio and change Verbose to Error. Then add this after running your app to the question.

Comment: I added the Logcat

Comment: you have a nullpointerException... are you aware of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `getView()` with a normal `View`. Replace your code with this:

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView counterText;
    private Button plusButton;
    private Button minusButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    private int counter;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

        counterText = view.findViewById(R.id.counterText);
        minusButton = view.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
        minusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        plusButton = view.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        resetButton = view.findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        initCounter();
        return  view;



    }

    private void initCounter() {
        counter = 0;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }


    private void minusCounter() {
        counter--;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }

    private void plusCounter() {
        counter++;
        counterText.setText(counter + "");
    }
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.minusButton:
                    minusCounter();
                    break;
                case R.id.plusButton:
                    plusCounter();
                    break;
                case R.id.resetButton:
                    initCounter();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The app crashes because you call `getView()` in `onCreate()` method, and the view is not created yet; you should only call `getView()` after `onCreateView()` is finished because onCreateView() inflates and returns this view.
You can refer to [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle) for more info.

Comment: So do I only copy `onCreateView()` at the beginnig of the code?

Comment: getView() returns the view that this fragment represents which is the fragment xml file; the fragment passes by multiple life cycle methods until it dies or destroys. You can use getView() in onStart(), or onResume(), so you can transfer the code from onCreate() to onStart()

Answer (score 0):

As M.Zain saied, remove the `getView()` from the `onCreate()`

You can get the View from `onCreate()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    counterText = findViewById(R.id.counterText);
    minusButton = findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    plusButton = findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    resetButton = findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    initCounter();
}
```

Or just try Kotlin, in Kotlin you don´t need any `findViewByID()`actions.